Добавление скролла при изменении масштаба графика в PyQt
Есть график с возможностью увеличения масштаба при нажатии на горячие клавиши.
Вопрос 1. Как добавить автоматическое добавление скролла (полосы прокрутки) по вертикали и горизонтали с возможностью перемещения по стрелкам. 
Вопрос 2: При изменении масштаба нужен перерасчёт значений координатных осей.
import sys
import math
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis
from PySide6.QtCore import QPointF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, Qt


class Charts(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Charts, self).__init__(parent)
        self.series1= QLineSeries()
        self.zoomFactor = 1.1
        self.zoom_value = 0   
        self.chart1 = QChart()
        for i in range(0,2500,1):
            self.series1.append([QPointF(i, math.sin(i * 0.01))])
        self.chart1.addSeries(self.series1)
        y_axis = QValueAxis()
        y_axis.setRange(-100, 100)
        y_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        y_axis.setTickInterval(20)
        x_axis = QValueAxis()
        x_axis.setRange(1, 2500)
        x_axis.setTickInterval(100)
        x_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        self.chart1.addAxis(x_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
        self.chart1.addAxis(y_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        self.chart1.legend().hide()

        self.chartview1 = QChartView(self.chart1)
        self.chartview1.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.chartview1)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent):
        key = keyEvent.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_W and self.zoom_value < 10:
            self.chartview1.chart().zoom(self.zoomFactor)
            self.zoom_value = self.zoom_value + 1
        elif key == Qt.Key_S and self.zoom_value > 0:
            self.chartview1.chart().zoom(1 / self.zoomFactor)
            self.zoom_value = self.zoom_value - 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    charts = Charts()
    charts.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


Попробуйте так:
'''
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis
from PySide6.QtCore import QPointF
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter, Qt
'''
import math
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *


x = 2500     
x_ = x - 1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.step = 1000
        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step,
        )
        self.scrollbar.setRange(0, x_)       
       
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)        
        
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.splitter, stretch=1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scrollbar)
        
        self.zoomFactor = 1.1 
        self.zoom_value = 0   
        
        self.series1 = QLineSeries()
        for i in range(0, 2500, 1):
            self.series1.append([QPointF(i, math.sin(i * 0.01))])
        _pen = QPen(Qt.red)
        self.series1.setPen(_pen)
  
        y_axis = QValueAxis()
        y_axis.setRange(-100, 100)
        y_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        y_axis.setTickInterval(20)
        
        x_axis = QValueAxis()
        x_axis.setRange(1, 2500)
        x_axis.setTickInterval(100)
        x_axis.setTickType(QValueAxis.TickType.TicksDynamic)
        
        self.chart1 = QChart()    
        self.chart1.addSeries(self.series1)
        self.chart1.addAxis(x_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignBottom)
        self.chart1.addAxis(y_axis, Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        self.chart1.legend().hide()
        
        self.chart1.createDefaultAxes()

        self.chartview1 = QChartView(self.chart1)
        self.chartview1.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.chartview1)
        self.onAxisSliderMoved(0)

    def keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent):
        key = keyEvent.key()
        if key == Qt.Key_W and self.zoom_value < 10:
            self.chartview1.chart().zoom(self.zoomFactor)
            self.zoom_value = self.zoom_value + 1
        elif key == Qt.Key_S and self.zoom_value > 0:
            self.chartview1.chart().zoom(1 / self.zoomFactor)
            self.zoom_value = self.zoom_value - 1

    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        for i in range(self.splitter.count()):
            chart_view = self.splitter.widget(i)
            if isinstance(chart_view, QtChart.QChartView):
                chart = chart_view.chart()
                chart = self.chart1
                for serie in chart.series():
                    chart.axisX(serie).setRange(value_min, value_max)
                    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        value2 = value + self.step
        value1 = value
        if value2 >= x_:
            value2 = x_
            value1 = value2 - self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(value1), math.ceil(value2))
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(500, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())




Отлично, благодарю Вас! Но как как сделать возможность перемещаться по графику (например стрелками), т.е. видеть то что ушло за край при увеличении масштаба.

@Garp попробуйте задать новый вопрос, показать код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо рассказать/показать что вы хотите сделать.
